# Fragmented text: Is this just a simulator glitch?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios11

This is with a Xcode9 beta 6 simulator.

Here's the problem:
[image]

If you scroll a little, it goes back to the way it's supposed to be:
[image]

Comment: It is difficult to imagine a bug outside the simulator that would cause that problem in the clock area unless you're explicitly capturing the whole screen and drawing it by hand.

Comment: This is a known bug that should be fixed in the Xcode 9 GM.

Comment: I'm seeing this and many other similar UI glitches in the GM also.

Comment: Also experiencing this very often! It's becoming very difficult to do anything.

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/32906330